# Can I use Split View on an older iPad model?

Tags: ipad, ios, multitasking

I can use Slide Over, but not Split View. Can I modify any plist files or do something in order to be able to use it on my iPad mini 2?

Comment: For example, I could make a backup, modify plist files, and then restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing that you can do to change that. iOS is *not* open-source, so users can't change source code. But it's also hardware limitations, so even if you were to find a way to force Split View multitasking into your iPad Mini, there's no telling what would happen. Apps would likely randomly crash, if they were even to open in the first place. Apple does a great job of supporting older hardware, so if Split View was feasible to implement on older iPads, Apple probably would have done it.

Comment: Perhaps it might not work as it would on the latest iPads, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I would not sign that. Apple do exclude older hardware deliberately although it is capable of supporting some features. Examples are Siri on iPhone 4 (it was an app before it was integrated into iOS), or slow-mo videos (60 fps and more were supported before they decided to make it an exclusive feature of iPhone 5 and removed it for older devices when they released the new iOS. Or multitasking gesture on iPads. Split View may therefore come to jailbroken systems, but this is another story and not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Install Medusa tweak from Cydia and you will get real splitview multitasking.